# Is there a limit on the number of versions of a file, that a versioned S3 bucket can store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

We are using versioned s3 bucket for our use-case.

We'll be frequently updating the same file.

I would like to know how many versions of same file can the s3 bucket handle.

I wonder whether the oldest version will be removed if there is a limit the max files that versioned s3 can handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy reachable limits for different versions, but you'll be charged for each stored version.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-enhancement-versioning/

> Normal S3 pricing applies to each version of an object. You can store any number of versions of the same object, so you may want to implement some expiration and deletion logic if you plan to make use of this feature.

So if you are going to update file frequently you should consider setting some S3 Lifecycle in advance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html